# How to embed Google Login button for authentication on web using firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I am planning to use google firebase for handling my website authentication but I cannot find any documentation on how to embed the google sign in button on my page. I don't plan to embed the default [platform.js](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) script as it is not being used to handle authentication.

All functionality is being handled by firebase. Also, I plan to use a custom UI and not the Firebase UI for the web.

The button text should also be customisable for different signup and sign-in button modes.

Comment: If you're not going to use firebase-ui, then you're on your own to build the UI.  Are you running into a particular problem?

Comment: I want to build the sign-in button following Google's branding guidelines. And so was looking how to embed it probably by fetching the image from some google CDN. Or unless firebase web js SDK exposes some method to generate the button which would solve the branding problem completely

Answer (score 4, accepted):

are you using angularfire for Firebase, if you're not using it's ok, try to go through this link [firebase Google Sign In Method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#popup-mode).

Firebase Google Sign in works like, it creates a new user if the user does not exist in the firebase Authentication if the user exists it will not the create user. So you don't need to worry about the sign in and sign up. Just provide it with Google Sign In. For Example, consider this scenario. If I am a new user to the Google Sign In, it will ask me to Sign In into the Gmail account, Once I am Logged it will never ask me to log in again unless I Log out, if I logged out the next time when in press Google Sign In, it will automatically log me in.

If your looking for code with button Login, please code it like below,

```
<input type="button" onclick=callGoogleSignIn() value="Google Sign In"/>
<script>
      function callGoogleSignIn(){
          var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
          firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
               // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
                var token = result.credential.accessToken;
               // The signed-in user info.
               var user = result.user;
               // ...
         }).catch(function(error) {
             // Handle Errors here.
               var errorCode = error.code;
               var errorMessage = error.message;
               // The email of the user's account used.
               var email = error.email;
               // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
               var credential = error.credential;
            // ...
         });
      }
</script>
```

Please feel free ask any doubts if you have and go through this site [For Firebase Google Log in](http://www.iceongo.com/). This site has developed the google log in with firebase, see how they used it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, got the logo from https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/blob/master/image/google.svg and embeded it on the button

Comment: No mention, I am happy that my answer helped you a bit.

Answer (score 0):

***### firebase based phone authentication ###***

***### firebase and code setup ###***

1. download this repository https://github.com/Varadsingh/google-phone-auth/archive/master.zip
2. go to https://console.firebase.google.com/project/
3. create a new project
4. go to the setting button and then click on "Project settings"
5. now in the "Your apps" section select the "Config" radio button
6. copy the code given
7. paste the code in /firebase/init.js change the variable name as required
8. now back to firebase console, in the "Develop" section click on "Authentication", then go to "Sign-in method", here in "Sign-in providers" section, click on "Phone" section and enable it
9. you can also add a dummy phone number and verification code for testing purpose
10. in the "Authorized domains" section, add your domain for example "localhost"

***### points to be noted ###***

1. the code runs properly on a server environment, meaning it won't run by just double-clicking on the html file
2. you need to copy the code to the root/htdocs/public_html folder on the server that you use example XAMPP
3. firebase authentication requires captcha verification, and in the code, the verification has been kept invisible, therefore it might take a few moments to initialize